# When load balancing, must all copies of static web page be exactly the same?

Tags: load-balancing

I am used to get answers for everything on the web, but not this time...

Yesterday I enable Amazon DNS weight functionally to load balance 7 websites between two different IP addresses (split 50%-50%). Both servers run IIS 8.5, sites runs well on both sides.

Today I found out that Google WebMasterTools is reporting fails error with file robots.txt, all close to 50% of access try errors. The robots.txt file is ok and accessible (even via Google testing URL page) on both servers.

Lets say current version of static web pages are on the first computer and the updated version of the same web pages are on the second computer. Can it be the problem?

When load balancing, can static web pages be slightly different from one host server to the other?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Load balancing is turn off. In the Amazon DNS (TTL is set to 60sec) I did move one site to the second host computer (the newer version).   Tomorrow, I will go back in Google WebMasterTools to see if the problem is really specific to load balancing.  This will double-check the robots.txt rendering.

Comment: The problem is specific to load balancing, no Google error with robot.txt using the second host.

Answer (score 0):

No, the content can be different. The load balancer will simply send traffic to each. It sounds like one server is having problems rendering the robots.txt and if you say it doesn't, then check again.

Comment: For sure the content can be different from a programmatic point of view. Not being said directly, my main concern is with Google. I don't want my websites to be seen as erroneous and or fraudulent by Google.

Comment: Googlebot could hit either node, depending on how they are balanced at that particular time. You'd need to look into the specifics of how constantly reverting content affects SEO, but I can't image that it'd be very positive.